# Polynomial derivative roots also solve equation $(x-a_1)^{-1} + \ldots + (x-a_n)^{-1}$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, polynomials

I am studying for an exam and I can't figure out how to solve the following problem:

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ be real numbers and the roots of an $n$-th degree polynomial $P(x)$.

Prove that if $P'(x) = 0$, then $x$ also solves the equation:
$$(x-a_1)^{-1} + \ldots + (x-a_n)^{-1},$$
where $P'(x)$ is the first derivative of the polynomial $P(x)$.

I would be very grateful if someone very to explain this.

Comment: If $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are all roots, and $\deg P(x)=n,$ what can you say about the structure of $P(x)$?

Comment: Well, a1,... an are the roots of P(x), so P(x)=(x-a1)(x-a2)...(x-an).

Comment: Up to a factor, yes: $P(x)=c(x-a_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-a_n).$ The next step would be to differentiate the polynomial. The rest looks as if a proof of induction could help.

Comment: I tried that... If you think you know how to solve it, could you write out the whole solution?

Comment: Hint: Compute $\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

If we write $P(x) = A(x-a_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-a_n)$, then by the product rule we have \begin{align}
P'(x) &= A(x-a_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-a_n) + A(x-a_1)(x-a_3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-a_n)+ \ldots \\
&= A \prod_{i\neq1}(x-a_i) + A \prod{i\neq 2} (x-a_i) + \ldots \\
&= A \sum_{j = 1}^n \prod_{i \ne j} (x-a_i) = 0
\end{align}
Simply dividing by the entire polynomial, we get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)=c\cdot \prod_i (x-a_i)$ means that $P'(x)=c\cdot \sum_j \prod_{i\neq j}(x-a_i).$ Finally divide the equation $P'(x)=0$ by $P(x)$.